# Airflow DAG triggered but bot running tasks

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am facing a strange situation while working with Airflow DAG. I am using Airflow container and have created a DAG to automatically backup my Atlassian artifacts to the S3 bucket using the following three steps in order:

1. `Create a directory structure if it does not exist`
2. `Run the Atlassian artifact backup script.`
3. `Move the backed-up artifacts to S3 and delete the files locally.`

The strange behavior which I encounter is that everything works perfectly fine when I manually trigger the DAG. However, the scheduled DAG gets triggered everyday correctly but individual task never gets executed. The first task `Create a directory structure if it does not exist` shows the following reason for dependency`Dagrun Running`:

```
Task instance's dagrun was not in the 'running' state but in the state 'success'.
```

The following tasks give the following reason for the dependency `Trigger Rule` statement:

```
Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 1 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'total': 1, 'successes': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0, 'upstream_failed': 0, 'done': 0}, upstream_task_ids={'create_directory'}
```